# Index for slow MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a large table with user votes. I tried nearly every tutorial and essay about INDEX usage and after failing that ... every possible combination of fields as keys, but the query stays slow.

Is there any Index I can use to speed this up?

(I will spare you my hidious attempts at indizes so far...)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `votes` (
    `uid` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `objectId` bigint(15) NOT NULL,
    `vote` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
    `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `unique input` (`uid`,`objectId`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

The table has around 1.3Million rows and will continue growing. This is the query i am trying:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT objectId, COUNT(uid) AS voteCount, AVG(vote) AS rating
FROM votes
GROUP BY objectId
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only approach I could suggest is the following, although I don't know if it would increase performance.  It assumes that you have an `Objects` table, with one row per `ObjectId`:

```
SELECT ObjectId,
       (select count(*) from votes v where v.objectid = o.objectid) as votecount,
       (select avg(vote) from votes v where v.objectid = o.objectid) as rating
FROM objects o;
```

Then you want the following index:  `votes(objectid, vote)`.

This would replace the outer `group by` with index scans, which may speed up the query.

Comment: Your right, I forgot the objectId in my sample SQL ... fixed

Comment: Are you sure the Optimizer will actually be faster with those two sub queries instead of one group by?

Comment: @ToBe . . . No.  I said it is worth a try.  This can be helpful in some cases, but I don't know if it will work better in your case.  I prefer the explicit `group by` approach, but sometimes you have to try to trick the engine.

Comment: It was much faster! lowered from ~3min to around 5sec. Tnx

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how an index will help to speed this up, because the average function will require that you interact with each and every row.  There's no WHERE clause.

Maybe you could create a VIEW that would amortize the cost for you.

Comment: I'll try that View idea.

Answer (score 1):

I think duffymo is correct. However you could try swapping the two columns in your unique key around (or add an index for objectid only) as it *may* help the GROUP BY.

Comment: I noticed that it is using the index on `objectId`, but only when I leave out any aggregation of `vote`, no matter what aggregation i use.

Comment: too bad then, duffymo was right, it`ll always have to do a full table scan to complete the aggregate (I suspect the count is being done on just the index).